# The bot encountered an error or bug. To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am a beginner in Azure BOT development. I am trying to run a sample source code in the following GitHub repo ( Developed in .net core 3.1 C# ). https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-proactive-installation/csharp

I had configured the `MicrosoftAppId` , `MicrosoftAppPassword`, `TeamsappcatalogAppId` values in the `appsettings.json` file. `ngrok` was already configured successfully. When I try to connect the BOT with the emulator the source throws an exception like the below image.

**exception.Message = "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')"**

[image]

Then it will throw the error message

[image]

What am I missing in the configuration?

Comment: Could you please add your source code instead of screenshot so that it can be reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is custom Bot sample created for Teams, I don't think it will work on all the channels e.g., Emulator/WebChat etc.

I think you should try running it on Teams itself. Also make sure that you have configured the [Teams Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on Azure Bot Service.

You can refer this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) for available Bot SDK samples.